# Can I instance a class that inherits the values of an instance of a superclass?

Tags: c#, oop

I am using C#, but I think this is a pretty generic OO question. Suppose I have a class called Animal, and it has properties like LegCount, EyeCount, HasFur, EatsMeat, etc.

Let's say I have an instance `a` of Animal. Suppose `a` has LegCount set to 4 and EyeCount set to 2.

Now, I'd like to create an instance `d` of type Dog, which inherits from Animal. I'd like to initialize `d` with all the values of `a`. I realize I could create a constructor or otherwise some other method that would take an Animal and spit out a new Dog with all the values copied in, but I was hoping there was some Object Oriented principle / trick that had me covered.

What I want to do, in plain English, is:

Create new Instance `d` of Dog, with all starting values from `a`. The key is "all", as opposed to specifying each property individually.

When you design a class that inherits from some other class, you don't need to list all the members it inherits. It just inherits all of them. So I am wondering if I can "inherit the values" on actual instances.

Comment: As far as pure OOP is concerned, I think that "[creating] a constructor or otherwise some other method that would take an Animal and spit out a new Dog with all the values copied in" actually -is- the trick. You can define a constructor of the form `Dog(Animal a)` as opposed to `Dog(int LegCount, int EyeCount, ...)`. You still may have to do the one-to-one assignment yourself, but from an OO standpoint this is the 'trick', AFAIK

Comment: It just seems like I should be able to say "Here's an Animal. Give me the most comprehensive Dog you can manage." with a keyword or two =)

Comment: I agree. Incidentally, `io` can do this, to a certain extent. You can actually subclass from an instance. http://iolanguage.com/ (I know that doesn't help in C#, but io is fun)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do what you're asking for with some C# language construct, you have to manually write mapping or delegating code. Or, take a look at [`AutoMapper`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) for that.

Comment: After reading everything here, it sounds like just copying a few properties is the right way to go, but I am appreciative of this answer because it helps me with a whole other problem I had! I was having these circular-reference warnings during serialization of some objects, and this will help me manage my simplified DTOs!

Answer (score 20):

The feature you want is called "prototype inheritance" or "[prototype-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming)". C# does not support this feature, so you're out of luck there.

You might consider using a language that supports prototype inheritance if your architecture fundamentally needs this feature. JavaScript is the most commonly used prototype inheritance language.

Prototype inheritance can be quite tricky to get correct if you're not careful. If this subject interests you, see my article on some of the bizarre situations you can run into with prototype inheritance in JScript:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/06/53352.aspx

Comment: I don't think I fundamentally need the feature. I'm still learning C# and OO, and wanted to make sure that before I did something else, I wasn't skipping some built-in way, causing future devs to maybe look at my code and think "but why didn't he just...". +1 for giving me the name of what I was thinking of. Now I can read all about it. I'll check out your blog post as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try a different approach with using the decorator pattern? An alternative to subclassing for extending functionality. Then all your values in the Animal class instance is preserved

http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx

Comment: +1 I was thinking along these lines but forgot about the decorator pattern. For this case I think it would work well, with wrappers like Quadruped, Carnivore, etc

Comment: You would need some sort of copying construct otherwise you would be modifying the item you use when decorating which could possibly cause problems if he is still using the Animal instance.

Comment: @John, can't the orginal object be preserved as an "inner" object, then the extensions is a part of the decorator contract?

Comment: Yeah, it can be preserved but since the Animal 'a' is a reference, it can cause issues if he wants to continue using 'a' in other places.  Modifying 'd.LegCount' will also modify 'a.LegCount'.  If OP doesn't need 'a' anymore then your answer is correct.

Comment: yes that is what decorator pattern is all about. Extending functionality, not modifying existing

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Animal
{
    public Animal(Animal otherAnimal)
    {
        if (otherAnimal == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("otherAnimal");

        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property 
            in typeof(Animal).GetProperties())
        {
            property.SetValue(this, property.GetValue(otherAnimal, null), null);
        }
    }
}
```

and then just call this Animal constructor from your Dog(Animal otherAnimal) constructor

But still you should to think over one more time about design of your classes and make Animal an abstract class. Because what do you imagine as instance of class Animal..